# Textbook suggestion: Multivariate Data Integration and PLS

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references, partial-least-squares

Apparently Partial Least Squares regression is very used in my field of research. I am looking for an applied textbook that covers Multivariate Data Integration methods, especially PLS and ideally its variants (e.g., Sparse PLS). Any suggestion? The ones I have mainly focus on PCA, Correlation Analysis, etc ... but they devote very little pages to PLS, if any.

Comment: *data integration*? In what sense, as in https://www.amazon.com/-/es/Eugenia-Kalnay/dp/0521796296/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_es_US=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=data+assimilation+meteorology&qid=1623450681&s=books&sr=1-1  or is data integration something other than data assimilation?